# How do I convert a multiple strings into a set of strings?

Tags: java

So I have following strings,

```
String a = "123, 541, 123"
String b = "527"
String c = "234, 876"
```

I would like to loop over these strings, split the string by "," and store it in a set of string so that I have such final output,

```
("123", "541", "527", "234", "876")
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

I have tried splitting the string but that results in `Set<String[]>` and not sure how to proceed with this since I am very new to this.

Comment: A loop isn't very helpful if you have 3 different variables. However, a loop can be useful if you have an array or list of strings, such as from `split()`. You should show the code that creates a `Set<String[]>` so that we can help you from what you already figured out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to separate strings in "a" and "c" variable. For that you can you can you split() method. You can try code below and adapt it in a way that fits your needs.

```
Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>();

String a = "123, 541, 123";
String b = "527";
String c = "234, 876";

private void addToSet(String stringNumbers) {
    
    for(String str : Arrays.asList(stringNumbers.split(","))) {
        strings.add(str);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This solves my issue. I replaced the for loop with `Collections.addAll` and that worked as well :D

Answer (score 2):

I would do it simply like that:

```
    String a = "123, 541, 123";
    String b = "527";
    String c = "234, 876";
    
    List<String> all = Arrays.asList((a + "," + b + "," + c).split(","));
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    for (String s : all) {
        result.add(s.trim());
    }

    System.out.println(result); // [123, 541, 234, 876, 527]
```

But I would try to the change the situtation that you have 3 different strings in the first place. Input should be an Array of Strings, so you don't have to care, if it is 1 or 37238273 different strings.

But without knowing where you have these 3 strings from, why they are 3 variables, hard to advice how to actually optimize that.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```java
List<String> all = Arrays.asList((a + ", " + b + ", " + c).split(", "));
```

Comment: `123` is duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach with Stream flat-mapping:

```
Set<String> result = Stream.of(a, b, c)
        .map(s -> s.split(", "))
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

try it plz.

```
Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
for (String s : (a + "," + b + "," + c).split(",")) {
    result.add(s.trim());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Java 9:

```
import java.util.Set;
Set<String> result = Set.of("123", "541", "527", "234", "876");
```

Comment: Likely down-voted because you ignore the details of the Question, and missed the point. The inputs are *not* separated into single number chunks. More curious is: Why did this Answer get up-voted?